# Xcode submission error: http request for the webDAV upload

Tags: xcode, upload, app-store-connect

I get the following errors while uploading my app to iTunes Connect:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

I am using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apple System Status page (https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) nothing is wrong, however, I am getting the same error (and upon retrying, a different one that says 'The network connection was lost').

I would just wait and see if this problem resolves itself in the next few hours.

My project is written in ObjC, so it has nothing to do with Swift.

[Update: after a few more retries, Xcode successfully submitted the app to iTunes Connect]

Comment: I'm getting the same error with Xcode and Application Loader. Can't submit my app to App Store.